# Нужно удалить несколько строк из базы данных Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Мы выбрали строки :

```
User::FindOne($id)
```

Нужно удалить каждую строку, у которой запись `mon` больше `20`.

Answer (score 1):

Может так

```
User::deleteAll(['>', 'mon', 20]);
```